# Select all next non-empty cells in Numbers

Tags: macos, numbers

Is there a way to **select all** next non-empty cells? as in pressing Shift+Ctrl+Arrow Key in Excel app

For example, I'm now at A1 and A5 is empty. ▼

[image]

By what means I can select A1 to A4 by one key shortcut or running some scripts? ▼

[image]

What I've already known here is the AppleScript of **jumping to** the next non-empty cell thanks to a guy called SGIII here in this post thread →  [How do I move/find the next non-empty cell - Apple Community_2019-09-25](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6347042)

The AppleScripts are as below:

```
--finds next next blank (or non-blank) cell in column
--select starting cell, and run
property searchFor : missing value
tell application "Numbers"
  set t to front document's active sheet's first table whose selection range's class is range
  tell t's selection range
  set currentRow to its first cell's row's address
  set searchCol to its first cell's column's address
  end tell
  tell t's column searchCol
  repeat with i from currentRow + 1 to count cells
  if cell i's value is searchFor then --add not if want to find non-blank
  set t's selection range to cell i
  return
  end if
  end repeat
  end tell
end tell
```